# How to prevent code duplication inside using statement System.Text.Encoding

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok how can i prevent code duplication in this particular case

The duplication happens due to streamreader character encoding.

In some cases i want to use default and in some cases i want to define myself.

`irCustomEncoding` is an integer

When i do not provide encoding what does application do as default ?

```
    using (Stream strumien = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        if (irCustomEncoding == 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strumien))
            {
                srBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(
strumien, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(irCustomEncoding)))
            {
                srBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

So what i am asking is how can i write single   `using (StreamReader...` instead of duplicating code

ty very much

c# wpf .net 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `Encoding.UTF8` if you don't have a different one:

```
var encoding = irCustomEncoding == 0 ? Encoding.UTF8
                                     : Encoding.GetEncoding(irCustomEncoding);
using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(strumien, encoding))
{
    srBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

(`Encoding.UTF8` is the default if you don't specify an encoding for `StreamReader`.)

Alternatively, you could get UTF8 by its [codepage number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
var codePage = irCustomEncoding == 0 ? Encoding.UTF8.CodePage : irCustomEncoding;
var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(codePage);
// Rest of the code as before
using (...)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ty very much for answer is UTF8 what application uses as default ?

Comment: and why TextReader instead of StreamReader  ?

Comment: You can also use `Encoding.Default`

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Using `Encoding.Default` would *not* be a good idea - that would change the behaviour to default to the platform-default encoding, which is almost certainly not the desired behaviour.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: UTF-8 is what `StreamReader` uses by default. And I generally only declare variables to be the type that I need them to be - we only need `ReadToEnd` from `TextReader`, so there's no need to require it to be `StreamReader`. That means if you later changed to (say) accept the reader from elsewhere, you could pass in a `StringReader` in testing.

Answer (score 5):

```
var sr = irCustomEncoding == 0
    ? new StreamReader(strumien)
    : new StreamReader(strumien, Encoding.GetEncoding(irCustomEncoding));

using (sr)
{
}
```

Comment: but will this dispose object after using statement ? since it is not created inside using statement

Comment: Yes, it will. Make sure not to reference it after the `using` block.

Answer (score 1):

First of all multiple `using` is not code duplication at all.

However u can simply things as :

```
Stream strumien;
StreamReader sr;

try
{
    sr = irCustomEncoding == 0 ? StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strumien) : StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(...);
    if (irCustomEncoding == 0)
    {
        srBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    else
    {
        // use sr
    }
}
finally
{
    strumien.Dispose();
    sr.Dispose();
}
```